# Conditional XML Validation against Multiple XSDs - ignore validation errors for certain XSDs and fail validation only for some XSDs

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

**Background** : Consuming XML from another system. Parse, validate & persist into own database.
Since not all fields are relevant to my system, Schema validation only for some element types.If validation fails, terminate execution.
Remaining types even if fail validation, still proceed to persist in DB.

I am validating an XML against a list of XSDs (One main XSD with includes for several XSDs). **Currently in my code, Validator is checking conformance to all included XSDs**.
However, requirement is - ***schema validation is to be made mandatory for certain XSDs. For a few others, even if XML element type does not conform to the XSD type, do not fail.*** How to do this?

e.g. Say, Person.xsd & Product.xsd is Mandatory for schema validation. Validation in Address.xsd & Phone.xsd can be ignored.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="com.demo.devika" xmlns:tns="com.demo.devika" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Address.xsd" />
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Phone.xsd" />
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="Product.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="Person" type="tns:Person_Type"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Person_Type">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FirstName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="LastName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="Address" type="tns:Address_Type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Phone" type="tns:Phone_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="Product" type="tns:Product_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

XML Validation Method

```
public boolean execute(InputStream inputXML) throws XMLStreamException, SAXException, IOException {

        // Creating Source array for Schema
        List<Source> schemaSources = schemaFiles.stream().map(schemaFile -> new StreamSource(schemaFile))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

        try {
            SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

            schemaFactory.setFeature(Constants.XERCES_FEATURE_PREFIX + Constants.NAMESPACE_GROWTH_FEATURE,
                    Boolean.TRUE);

            Schema schemaGrammar = schemaFactory
                    .newSchema(schemaSources.toArray(new StreamSource[schemaSources.size()]));

            Validator schemaValidator = schemaGrammar.newValidator();

            schemaValidator.validate(new StreamSource(inputXML));
            return true;

        } catch (SAXException | IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            inputXML.close();
        }

    }
```